# I work in BDD and I try to run test scenarios by TestNG class. In my group "Sanity" all tests run by Alphabet,I need to run it one after another

Tags: testng

[It's my group of tests that I need to run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9Ii7.png)
When I run the TestNG the first test is @AddPrePaidCard cause it begins with A, but I need to run @Install the first. I tried to run the tests without a defined name but it still according to Alfbet.

Comment: Please add your code in the question itself. rather than as an image

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `preserve-order="true"` attribute for the `<test>` tag:

`<test name="IOS Monyx test" preserve-order="true">`